# What are the common abbreviation for minimum in equations?

Tags: notation, maxima-minima

I'm searching for some symbol representing minimum that is commonly used in math equations.

Comment: Wait - what's wrong with 'min'?

Comment: @awesomeguy I assume it is the same as the difference between the operation **+** and a theoretical function **plus(x,y)**.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you are looking for a symbol (and for some reason want to avoid the clear, and much more common notation "$\text{min}$"), I believe that some people use $\wedge$ -  see [here](http://www.numericana.com/answer/symbol.htm#chevron).

Comment: Indeed, $\wedge$ is a common abbreviation for min, and similarly $\vee$ for max. Especially, it seems, in probability theory. For example, in stochastic processes, a process $X_t$ stopped at a time $T$ is often written as $X^T_t\equiv X_{t\wedge T}$. Using $\vee$ and $\wedge$ is less cumbersome that max/min, especially in subscripts and superscripts.

Answer (score -6):

The choice of symbol, depends mainly on the mathematics, physics, or programming discipline the equation is used in.

Merrian-Webster defines *minimum* as "the least quantity assignable, admissible, or possible."

For ordering, *minimum* means 'less than or equal to', which
is symbolized in some/many mathematics disciplines as ≤. 
List A = [1 0 1 0], List B = [1 1 0 0];  List (A[i]≤B[j] = [1 0 0 0].
For Boolean algebras, just multiply the two lists to generate the minimums:
List (A[i]*[j] = [1 0 0 0].  For Boolean Algebra * is a 'minimum' operator,
whereas + is a 'maximum' operator.

But, as mentioned above,  'min' is OK, as most programming languages
use some variant of min(). but C does not. Program comments would use either
'min' or '<=, both easy ASCII typing.

Stochastic processes use ∧ for minimum; however mathematical logic uses ∧
to mean logical conjunction or AND.